# Trying to standardize employer names column

Tags: python-3.x

`injury_df.Employer.value_counts()` shows that:

```
U.S. Postal Service                           103
UPS                                            46
U.S. POSTAL SERVICE                            44
United States Postal Service                   38
USPS                                           31
```

The postal service has been classified as several different employer because of the capitals in one case and an acronym in another. I want to collapse all these into one "U.S Postal Service".
I tried the following code:

```
injury_df['Employer'] = injury_df['Employer'].replace(['U.S. POSTAL SERVICE','United States Postal Service ','USPS'],'U.S. Postal Service')
```

But it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['U.S. Postal Service'],
                   ['UPS'],
                   ['U.S. POSTAL SERVICE'],
                   ['United States Postal Service'],
                   ['USPS'],
                   ['UPS'],
                   ['United States Postal Service']], columns=['Employer'])
```

`df['Employer'].value_counts` would yield:

[image]

Using the `replace` command:

```
df['Employer'] = df['Employer'].replace(['U.S. POSTAL SERVICE',
                                         'United States Postal Service',
                                         'USPS',
                                         'UPS'], 'U.S. Postal Service')
```

And as one would expect, after `df['Employer'].value_counts`:

[image]

Try to reproduce that and let me know. Perhaps sharing more information on your particular error would help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked. I don't understand where exactly I went wrong